# Memory exhaused in Laravel unit tests

Tags: php, laravel, unit-testing, out-of-memory

I wrote unit tests for my controller. My class is

```
class ApiControllerTest extends TestCase
```

and it contains test methods like this

```
public function testAgeDistribution()
    {
        $response = $this->action(...,
            ['datasetName'=>'AgeDistribution',
              'min_longitude'=>-80.60, 'max_longitude'=>-78.60,
                'min_latitude'=>43.20, 'max_latitude'=>44,
                'zoom'=>12
                ]);



        $this->assertResponseOk();

        $json = json_decode($response->content());

        $this->checkMainThings($json, 'AgeDistribution', 'Population', 7, 100, 7);
    }
```

All methods are similar but with different parameters and checks.

In the beginning of handler function I have a row

```
$start_memory = memory_get_usage();
```

And I see (in debugger) that each new test it has more and more memory used.

In other words, memory is not freed between tests.

How to free memory in PHP or what potential error I have in tested methods?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

PHPUnit doesn't clean up after itself. One option is to extend TestCase and free up memory in the `tearDown`:

```
abstract class TestCase extends Illuminate\Foundation\Testing\TestCase
{
    public function tearDown()
    {
        parent::tearDown();

        $refl = new ReflectionObject($this);
            foreach ($refl->getProperties() as $prop) {
            if (!$prop->isStatic() && 0 !== strpos($prop->getDeclaringClass()->getName(), 'PHPUnit_')) {
                $prop->setAccessible(true);
                $prop->setValue($this, null);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Can't I write this in my own class?

Comment: Of course, that is what I am suggesting. Make a small TestCase extension and have your tests extend it instead of the base TestCase.